# In Asp.net Empty website, How to change "Web.config" to make contents(.js) file displaying in Browser rather than downloading

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iis-7

My Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Disposition" value="inline" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I try to build a  kind of html 
the url is a .js file, IE browser always force me to download it
other browser just displays the contents
Can I configure the Web.config to force every browser to display the .js contents in webpage?
thanks

Asp.net 4.5  IIS express in VS2013

Comment: Why do you want to view JSON directly in the browser in the first place? Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).Wouldn't it be better to display the data as HTML? Or if you need to see the structure as JSON, perhaps embed it in some HTML in a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: <a href=".js file link url">Link </a>  After hit the link IE always ask me if I need to download the  .js file, I just want to display its contents in webpage

Comment: Your previous comment didn't shed any light on why you want to do this. Please explain.

Comment: I edit my comment, it is possible to configure the web.config, to force to display contents in webpage for this url?

Comment: Probably. But like I said, the easiest way would be to embed the JSON in an HTML page inside a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: But I need to get the contents dynamically using that url

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an alternate approach. We'll load the JSON and display it in an HTML page.

ASPX

```
<pre id="JsonViewer" runat="server">
</pre>
```

Code Behind C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = "~" + Request.QueryString["JsonPath"]; //ex, Default.aspx?JsonPath=/Data/file.json
    var json = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(url));
    JsonViewer.InnerText = json;
}
```

Comment: Is that possiable to make the approach for all situation, to make a rule like    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=query.js" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: @EricPeng Internet Explorer can override inline content if it wants to. So it'd be better to display it wrapped in HTML like in my answer. By the way, your question says ".json", but your comments say ".js". They're not the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, All my code is HTML and Javascript, I just using an asp.net server, running in IIS express to display HTML page

Comment: @EricPeng I tested this and it works. Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @EricPeng Well, add an ASPX page! Or a generic handler as I described in my other example. You tagged this question as ASP.NET, don't be surprised if you receive ASP.NET based answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with a generic handler (.ashx). I haven't tested this.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var url = "~" + context.Request.QueryString["JsonPath"]; //ex, JsonHandler.ashx?JsonPath=/Data/file.json
    var json = File.ReadAllText(context.Server.MapPath(url));
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(json);
}
```